# Unclear on why Meissel's approach to counting primes works

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, math-history

I am reading through the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) on prime counting.

The following is presented to describe Meissel's approach:

- Let $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n$ be the first $n$ primes.
- Let $\Phi(m,n)$ be the number of integers $x \le m$ where $\gcd(x,p_n\#)=1$ where $p_n\#$ is the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) for $p_n$.

I am clear on the first formula:

> $$\Phi(m,n) = \Phi(m,n-1) - \Phi(\frac{m}{p_n},n-1)$$

It's the second formula that is giving me trouble:

- For a given integer $m$, let $n = \pi(\sqrt[3]{m})$ where $\pi(x)$ is the [prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).
- Let $\mu = \pi(\sqrt{m}) - n$

Then:

> $$\pi(m) = \Phi(m,n) + n(\mu + 1) + \frac{\mu^2 - \mu}{2} - 1 -  \sum_{k=1}^{\mu}\pi(\frac{m}{p_{n+k}})$$

I can neither understand why this would be true nor why it would be useful in counting primes.

If someone could explain high level why it is true and why it is useful or provide a reference that can help me to understand the second formula, I would greatly appreciate it.  The wikipedia article by itself is not clear to me.

---

Edit:  I believe that I am clear on the second formula.

Please let me know if any of my thoughts are incorrect (or if there is a more precise/concise way to say any point):

- $\mu$: the count of primes $p_i > p_n$ that divides at least one [semiprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime) $\le m$
- $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\mu}\pi(\frac{m}{p_{n+k}})$: the number of ways to form semiprimes $\le m$ which are divisible by some prime $p$ where $\sqrt[3]{m} < p \le \sqrt{m}$
- $\Phi(m,n)-1$: the count of primes and semiprimes $\le m$ where each [lpf](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastPrimeFactor.html) $\ge p_{n+1}$.
- $\dfrac{\mu^2 - \mu}{2}$: number of nonsquare semiprimes composed of primes $p_i,p_j$ where $p_n < p_i,p_j \le \sqrt{m}$
- $n(\mu + 1)$: the first $n$ primes + the number of semiprimes $\le m$ where $lpf \le p_n$ and [gpf](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatestPrimeFactor.html)$ > p_n$

Comment: Each summand counts all possible combinations of products of primes in order to "cover" all numbers $\leq m$ and not to get primes greater than $m$.Basically I believe it is not so useful but is another way to rephrase some known sieve techniques.By the way I admire you because you are not a mathematician but you are devoted to mathematics so much!!!

Comment: Thanks Konstantinos.  You've actually answered my question about usefulness.  It is probably useful because it impacted sieve techniques.  I'll keep digging.  I'm very interested in getting clear how each summand contributes to a full count. I'll read up on sieve techniques to better understand how this formula impacted them.  Cheers.  :-)

Comment: Why it is useful is that it is *much* faster than sieving for getting prime counts.  Counting the first 10^14 primes in under 30 seconds.  This does require some interesting optimizations of the phi function, but the result is 1000x faster than sieving (and will keep getting faster as the input size increases).